# Swift: Want timer to start from value i set not from the beginning

Tags: ios, timer, swift

Here I have code of my timer with two buttons "start" and "stop". Have stepper to set value for my timer but when I set any value using stepper and then press start button timer runs from the beginning not from the value I set.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = Int()


    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!



    @IBAction func changeValueStepper(sender: UIStepper) {

        valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
        timer.invalidate()


    }

    @IBAction func startTimerButton(sender: UIButton) {

        timer.invalidate()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    }

    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {

      timer.invalidate()


    }

    func update() {

        valueLabel.text = String(counter++)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
```

Comment: `changeValueStepper()` only sets the label text, but not the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeValueStepper` only updates the label text but not your counter variable.
I cannot see in your code where `counter` is initalized.